# How do I kill a process without knowing its process ID?

Tags: process

If I close a process gameconqueror is attached to, before closing gameconqueror, the application (gameconqueror) continues to run, spamming "Failed to attach to process: No such process." Or similar error. gameconqueror cannot be sent kill through process name, nor process ID since gameconqueror doesn't use its own binary as a name for its process. Nor does it use scanmem unless it's actually scanning.

Answer (score 6):

to kill a process *proc* type:

```
pkill proc
```

If you dont know the name of *proc* you can type

```
pkill pr
```

and hit tabular. You will get a list of all processes running and beginning with *pr*

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal type

```
ps ax | grep gameconqueror
```

**At the beginning** in the resulting line/s there is the Process ID.

[image]

To kill the process, you have to enter:

```
sudo kill -9 <process id 1> <process id 2>
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work also:

```
sudo killall -SIGKILL gameconqueror
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, when I had problem with firefox and killing it

```
sudo killall -9 firefox-bin
```